# Implementation of Task in monodroid

Tags: c#, java, mono, parallel-processing, xamarin.android

I'm a .net developer and I'm using monodroid these days. I found Task class in the mono droid. I'm not sure how does monodroid implement it. I guess it uses thread pool in Java, am I right? I appreciate if there is any article for me to read.

Thanks,
Howard

Comment: TPL is a pretty cool feature in .net framework 4.0. Here is an article for this, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, MonoDroid does not use the threadpool in Java. Check out the implementation of [System.Threading.Tasks](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading.Tasks) in Mono.

Comment: This is really useful, thanks a lot. I also want to know what is it after compiling. In another word, can I implement it in pure Java? Just consider that if I want to use Android and also want to implement the same thing I did in the MonoDroid with TPL.

Comment: After compiling you get MSIL (your program + Mono classes that your program uses + the mono runtime), not java bytecode. If you want pure Java you don't need Mono for Android...